# Floating :after under the element

Tags: css, hover, css-float, css-position

So I seem to be stuck on a simple piece of a css code.

What I want to do is put 3 dots directly under the menu when I hover over it. I've had no problem with making them appear on hover, but when I want to position them under the element the whole thing gets odd.

When I add a margin the dots move, but with them also moves the whole element, so I am no closer to moving them under, all I manage to do is move the whole element.

Here is the css code:

```
.current-menu-item li.selected::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "...";
  color: #f2f;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em 0 0 2em;
  text-align: center;   
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  z-index: -1;
}

.avia-menu-text::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "...";
  color: #f2f;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em 0 0 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 4px;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  z-index: -1; 
}

.current-menu-item li.selected:hover:after{
  content: "...";
  color: #f2f;
  float: left;  
  margin: 2em 0 0 2em;
  text-align: center;   
  visibility: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  z-index: -1;
}

.avia-menu-text:hover:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "...";
  color: #f2f;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em 0 0 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 4px;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

The snippet of html code

```
<span class="avia-menu-text"> $text </span>
```

Also if I could get a suggestion? Should I use the checkbox hack so when a menu is selected the dots also show or should I do it in js?

Comment: can you add html as well? maybe as a snippet so we see a full picture?

Comment: I could add more code, but there is no real point to it simply due to the fact that in the php file all I'm doing is calling functions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)